# How do I install & configure Flash in Chromium > 56 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: flash, chromium

I performed the following two commands to install Flash:

```
$ sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
$ sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

However, website elements that make use of Flash, are not properly displayed. See, for instance, the following Flash-based music player:

[image]

**Question:**

How do I properly set up Flash on Chromium 56 and later?

**More information:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, you don't need both those packages (and `pepperflashplugn-nonfree` for 16.10 is broken at the moment, even if it's about to be fixed).

The first thing I would do is:

```
sudo apt purge adobe-flashplugin pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Then close the browser and open it again.

Please see [Install the Flash plug-in](https://help.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) for a general overview about Flash on Ubuntu.

*Edit:*

In a comment you told us that you have the vivid pocket of Canonical Partner enabled, which is wrong. You can change it with this command:

```
sudo sed -i -r 's/vivid (partner)/yakkety \1/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and the latest version of `adobe-flashplugin` should be installed.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your procedure but Flash is still not working inside Chromium.

Comment: @orschiro: How did you determine that it's not working? What does it say if you go to [this page](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)?

Comment: I very much appreciate your help! My apologies for my delayed response. This page shows me this [installation note](http://i.imgur.com/gq51mMI.png). So, I seem to have Flash installed and working, correct? However, why can't I see the Flash-based web player on [this](https://www.sheetgo.com/google-cloud-next-17/) site then? It only displays [this black bar](http://i.imgur.com/T31shfi.png).

Comment: @orschiro: You seem to have an old Flash version hanging around somehow. The latest version provided by `adobe-flashplugin` is 24.0.0.221, not 20.0.0.267. Did you run the commands I proposed successfully? Can you please run the command `locate libpepflashplayer.so` and let us know what it outputs?

Comment: Might this cause the problem?  `Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid/partner amd64 adobe-flashplugin amd64 1:20151228.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 [10.2 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid/partner amd64 adobe-flash-properties-gtk amd64 1:20151228.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 [113 kB]
`

Comment: @orschiro: Yes. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just don't know what else I am missing. Now, [I seem to have the latest version](http://i.imgur.com/t1JDYYO.png) but these Flash-based web elements [still don't show up](http://i.imgur.com/kJ2BDkP.png). Another example: https://degrowthaudiobook.wordpress.com/

Comment: @orschiro: I would stick to what `adobe-flashplugin` provides, since that way Flash will be updated as part of the regular package updates. There must be something else, and the only thing I can think of is that some codec package is missing. Try to install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

Comment: Despite having installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, these web players still don't show up. :-( Maybe it's not even a Flash problem? Do they work for you?

Comment: @orschiro: They work fine for me with Firefox, but when I just tried with Chromium I saw the same black bars as you do. :( I suspect it's something with Chromium and mp3 files, and I'd suggest that you ask another question about that specifically. (Or try some other browser...) The problem is probably not Flash related.

Comment: Finally, we found the problem. Thanks! I will file a Chromium bug report.

Comment: You can find the bug report [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704031).

Answer (score 1):

have you considered upgrading flash entirely? 
I've been using the adobe beta for flash in both firefox and chrome for several months now and I've had great results. those pesky sites that require windows or mac because your flash version isn't up to spec, have completely stopped being a bother to me.
Some people get squimish at the sound of a beta, But, it might just solve your problems. the installation instructions can be found in the tarball at the download site if you need them

http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html

Comment: I appreciate your help! I followed these instructions. However, please see my latest comment above in response to Gunnar's answer. I still cannot get it to work. Does it work for you?

Comment: The difference between beta and the released version is small today, and by using beta you create a maintenance problem compared to using the `adobe-flashplugin` package. No sites require the beta version AFAIK.